# Requisição jQuery Post + PHP + MySQL não grava os dados

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Estou realizando um cadastro via jQuery Ajax, para tanto criei a seguinte função:

```
function salvarCadastro(titulo, form, caminho) {
    var dadosFormulario = $("#" + form).serialize();

    var myData = $("#" + form).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: caminho,
        dataType: "text",
        data: myData,
        cache: false,
        success:function(response){
            data = data.trim();
            if (data == 'S') {
                alert('Dados registrados com sucesso.');
            } else {
                alert('Não foi possivel registrar os dados!');
            }
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert('Houve um prolema de requisição ao ' + titulo');
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

No meu arquivo php ficou desta forma:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'teste');

    $id        = $_POST['id'];
    $ordem     = $_POST['ordem'];
    $descricao = utf8_decode(trim($_POST['descricao']));

    $sql = "UPDATE dados SET ordem = '$ordem', descricao = '$descricao' WHERE id = $id";

    $mysql->query($sql);
    if (empty($mysql->error)) {
        echo "S";
    } else {
        echo "N";
    }
    $mysql->close();
?>
```

Se eu realizar um post diretamente do formulário para o arquivo PHP ele me retorna "S" o mesmo ocorre via Ajax, porem via Ajax não ele não grava as informações no banco.

Comment: Adicione também seu HTML na pergunta. Pode ser alguma coisa lá.

Comment: Eu diria que isso é impossível, tem certeza que o AJAX está executando a mesma URL que você está executando diretamente?

Comment: Você tem certeza que os dados estão sendo passados via AJAX? Eu nunca usei dataType: "text", mas sim 'json'... Tente. O que é data? De onde tirou essa variável? `data = data.trim();` Você não está usando o retorno no ajax em nenhum lugar (response)... Esse retorno deveria estar na sua comparação no seu if e não o data.

Comment: Veja se os dados estão realmente chegando no script via ajax. Acho que o erro só pode estar nesse ponto.

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma forma mais fácil que eu uso. Tente no código em PHP, no lugar do "S" e "N" colocar `echo "<script> alert ('mensagem'); <\script>";` ou é algo na string da query.

Eu faço assim e sempre funcionou.

```
 $sql = "UPDATE dados SET ordem = '".$ordem."', descricao = '".$descricao."' WHERE id = ".$id;
```